# Creating Query using Date parameters with Spring Jpa Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to execute a query via JpaRepository that uses Date objects as parameters (java.util.Date). However, each time the method from the repository is called, it returns a null value. When I pass Integer values and work with id instead of Date I don't get any errors and the query is successfully executed.

This is my query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT sum(o.price) FROM Order o WHERE o.dateCreatedAt BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2")
Double getTotalMoneyEarned(Date beginDate, Date endDate)
```

I don't know if I'm missing something. In my Order model object, dateCreatedAt is a column of type Date.

Comment: turn on sql logging so you can see what sql is being executed

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at **imports** block

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
```

This should work :

```
@Query(value="SELECT sum(o.price) FROM Order o WHERE o.dateCreatedAt BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate")
Double getTotalMoneyEarned(@Param("beginDate") Date beginDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate)
```